# econfguration incorrect while trying to install ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, system-installation, configuration, windows-xp

I am trying to run ubuntu 12.04LTS off of a pc I found off the side of the road
pentium 4 3.00ghz
512mb ram
128mb gpu
20gb hdd

Problem is when I place my cd inside and press f11 to access boot menu, it won't boot from cd and starts windows xp

If I try to open up the cd in xp, it says:
D:\
This application has failed to start because the application is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem

I've tried burning this again and also re downloading ubuntu, I even went as far as to open it in my windows 8 system (which allowed it) but it just won't do anything in this pc.

I've also tried to do it from other xp pc's and it's not working also

I know that the dvd-r works, but for some reason won't work in windows xp (no service pack) I'll try re-download the service packs to see if that is the issue but I doubt it

Please help, cheers

Comment: Make sure you have the 32 bit version of Ubuntu. Can you bout the other xp PC from the CD?

Comment: Secondly, for make sure your CD drive is set as first boot drive in BIOS. A CD can not change your option in BIOS. A side note: Ubuntu 12.04 may be sluggish in your system

Answer (score 1):

To change boot drive order in BIOS:

1. Power down PC
2. Hold down the <kbd>F10</kbd> Key
3. Turn on power (be sure that <kbd>F10</kbd> is still held down)

   When the PC starts to boot you will be redirected to a screen asking you whether you want to go to setup or continue with boot.
4. Select <kbd>F2</kbd> and go to setup

   Navigation in setup will depend on your BIOS but there should be a boot order you can manipulate to boot from CD (or Optical drive), HDD, etc...